# Linux how to copy but not overwrite?

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I want to `cp` a directory but I do not want to overwrite any existing files even it they are older than the copied files. And I want to do it completely noninteractive as this will be a part of a Crontab Bash script. Any ideas?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67539/how-to-rsync-only-new-files

Comment: [SuperUser - Copy files in linux but avoid the copy if files do exist in destination](https://superuser.com/questions/118781/copy-files-in-linux-avoid-the-copy-if-files-do-exist-in-destination)

Comment: **TL;DR:** For files, `cp -n copyFile pasteFile`, but for directories, `cp -r -n copyDir pasteDir`

Answer (score 797, accepted):

Taken from the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/cp.1.html):

```
-n, --no-clobber
              do not overwrite an existing file (overrides a previous -i option)
```

Example:

```
cp -n myoldfile.txt mycopiedfile.txt
```

Comment: Note, this will exit with an error if the file exists. To exit with success, try

```cp -n source.txt destination.txt || true```

Comment: @galenandrew `cp -n` does not exit with error if the file exists on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @galenandrew Confirmed. Thank you. My project wasn't building in Xcode after adding a run script to my target.

Comment: @AaronFranke looks like it does.

Comment: Even with Ubuntu 18.04, the behavior is the same, that when the file exists, the command exit without erro, that is, an no op! This is dangerous!

Comment: `cp -n source.txt dest.txt || test -f dest.txt` won't ignore error if `source.txt` and `dest.txt` are missing

Comment: FWIW, I have noticed that a *needed* `-n` exits `1` on Arch, but exits `0` on Manjaro. So, the behavior seems to be connected to the stack, similarly to how `cp -i` is often a link for `cp` in `.bashrc` on desktop distros. I only found this because I didn't stop at testing on my desktop, but on the actual machine it would be used—always test on your identical setup, not merely a distro related to the stack.

Comment: And, it would work for `cp -n myfolder/* newfolder/` with identical behavior, and will not break if encountering an existing file where the `-n` is needed.

Comment: always read your man page - that's the main takeaway from this answer at least IMO

Answer (score 141):

Consider using [`rsync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

```
rsync -a -v --ignore-existing src dst
```

---

As per comments `rsync -a -v src dst` is not correct because it will update existing files.

Comment: You want to add the `--ignore-existing` flag to prevent existing files from being overwritten.

Comment: Complete command `rsync -a -v --ignore-existing <src> <dst>` is indeed the correct answer, instead of `cp -u`above.

Comment: If a previous copy was interrupted and only a truncated file copied, I'm sure cp -u won't re-copy it... but will rsync, with --ignore-existing? Probably not either... so that makes them perfectly equivalent, right?

Comment: rsync keeps the file timestamp while cp uses the current time (in my experience)

Comment: You can use `--preserve=timestamps` with `cp` to preserve the timestamps.

Comment: some servers just has no rsync

Comment: absolutely. I don't want to install `rsync` into my docker container, just to do a copy! I can't imagine why we should use a cannon when a BB gun will suffice.

Answer (score 65):

```
cp -n
```

Is what you want. See the man page.

Comment: The man page: `-n    Do not overwrite an existing file.  (The -n option overrides any previous -f or -i options.)`

Answer (score 40):

This will work on RedHat:

```
false | cp -i source destination 2>/dev/null
```

*Updating* and *not overwriting* is something different.

Comment: What does `false` do here?

Comment: @FrozenFlame Answers `-i` questions.

Comment: Obviously, this command won't work if you'll try to copy more than ARG_MAX files.
To work-around this case,  check this [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110285).

Comment: Also obviously, this command won't work if the earth crashes into the sun.

Comment: @ceving I think you'll find that `oh-my-zsh` has an alias for that use-case.

Answer (score 37):

For people that find that don't have an 'n' option (like me on RedHat) you can use `cp -u` to only write the file if the source is newer than the existing one (or there isn't an existing one).

[edit] As mentioned in the comments, this will overwrite older files, so isn't exactly what the OP wanted. Use ceving's answer for that.

Comment: OP asked not to overwrite existing files **even if they are older than copied files**, so `-u` doesn't actually fit purpose.

Comment: Goodness, you're absolutely right. I'm surprised it took so long for anyone to notice.

Comment: It might not be what the OP asked for, but it's exactly what I needed for my Uberspace (Centos 7). Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad six years ago me could help :-D

Answer (score 17):

**Alpine linux:** Below answer is only for case of single file: in alpine `cp -n` not working (and `false | cp -i ...` too) so solution working in my case that I found is:

```
if [ ! -f env.js ]; then cp env.example.js env.js; fi
```

In above example if `env.js` file not exists then we copy `env.example.js` to `env.js`.

Answer (score 9):

Some version of cp do not have the *--no-clobber* option. In that case:

```
  echo n | cp -vipr src/* dst
```

Comment: Super good suggestion. I lost a lot of time debugging scripts until I realised the --no-clobber option is not available everywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Work like a charm!

Answer (score -3):

This works for me
yes n | cp -i src dest

Comment: It is much more effective to use the '--no-clobber' instead of forcing interactive copy with negative input.