# Is there a way to check whether `cp -r` would overwrite anything?

Tags: bash, cp

Is there a way to check if `cp -r` would overwrite anything, without actually copying anything?

`-n` seems to copy files that don't collide, which is not what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux how to copy but not overwrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392735/linux-how-to-copy-but-not-overwrite)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187937/how-to-test-which-files-will-be-copied-with-the-cp-command

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the `rsync` command there you have a lot of parameters to override the target or delete files on the target if you want.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

or like mentioned in the comments you could use `cp -n` for `--no-clobber`. But in general i would suggest rsync there you have a lot more possibilities.

Comment: Agree. If you need to know, cp is not the right tool.

Comment: Note that cp has the -i --interactive option and the -n, --no-clobber option.

Answer (score 0):

cp has the -i --interactive option and the -n, --no-clobber option.
See `man 1 cp'.

Answer (score 0):

To only check if the file exists in the target location, but not actually perform any copying you can use the `diff` command with the `-r` option.

From `man diff`:

> -r, --recursive
>   recursively compare any subdirectories found

```
diff -r --brief --report-identical-files /source-folder/ /target-folder/ | grep -v '^Only in'
```

- `--brief` is listing files that differ (same as `-q`)
- `--report-identical-files` does the same for files that don't differ (same as `-s`)
- The `grep -v '^Only in'` removes files that are only in one directory tree, because those will not be overwritten.

The output will look something like this:

```
Files /source-folder/file1.txt and /target-folder/file1.txt are identical
Files /source-folder/file2.jpg and /target-folder/file2.jpg differ
```